# How is it decided that a package goes to Ubuntu Core or into "universe" (the Community)?

Tags: source-packages

It seems to me that Ubuntu has to main categories of packages.

There are the officially Ubuntu packages supported and maintained by Canonical itself: Ubuntu Core.
And there are the freetime maintained community packages in "universe".

Am I right so far?

How is it decided if a package goes to universe or core?

Comment: I doubt that any one here can answer that. This site is manned by volunteers and no one works for the company.

Comment: The duplicate I think matches your question (*or an answer did in my opinion; see start answer by muru*), but you can see https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu   I'm involved with a few Ubuntu teams, and not all comes from Debian (*Debian is preferred, but if Debian is too old or freezes get in the way; going direct upstream allows for newer packages*), detail that could be missed in the answer I felt applied.

Comment: Background reading: The relationship between Canonical and Ubuntu: https://ubuntu.com/community/canonical

Comment: Background reading: The four primary Ubuntu repositories: https://askubuntu.com/questions/58364/whats-the-difference-between-multiverse-universe-restricted-and-main

Comment: Wrong terms: "core" refers to Ubuntu Core, a snap-only flavor of Ubuntu. You probably meant the "Main" deb repository.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The decision process is simple:

- If the software is required for the install process (like `parted`)
- Or will be one of the final applications on the stock installed system (like `network-manager` or `libreoffice`)
- Or one of their dependencies (like `openssl`)

...then it goes into Main.

All other open source software with a compatible license goes into Universe.

In other words, when you install Ubuntu and first reboot into the newly-installed system (no customization), 100% of your installed packages are in Main...and very little else is in Main.